Does my shed roof need purlins for steel roofing?
I am attempting to build a shed to store my firewood. Since I'm new to woodworking/carpentry work, I decided to 3D model the shed before actually building it. Here're two views of the shed. The floor space of the shed is exactly 8'x 3'. I am struggling a bit with the design of the roof. I was planning to use corrugated, galvanized metal roof panels to construct the roof.


(i) Can I attach the panels directly onto the rafters (as shown in my 3D model above)? It seems more conventional to either put a sheet of plywood on top of the rafters, or put horizontal beams on top of the rafters onto which they attach the roof, like the photo below. Is this really necessary? It seems to just increase cost. Other than rain we usually don't get snow where I live.

(ii) the current roof, as drawn in my 3D model, is 9'x 5'. It seems that my local hardware store sells sheets in 2'x 8'. This would require 5 of those sheets to cover this roof, which doesn't seem to be particularly economical. Any suggestions on how to do this more efficiently?

How do you get 5 sheets? You shouldn't need 80sf of material to cover 45sf of roof. 3 sheets gives you 48sf, which is sufficient to cover 45sf.

@NuclearHoagie, one assumes a desire to avoid butt lap joints. Also, ~8% overage isn't always enough considering the nuances of fitment.

Most metal roofing runs from top to bottom.  You do need wood going across the rafters to add strength to the roofing.  This is usually 1x3s or 1x4s.  Unless a very good sale on 2x8 roofing sheets, can get 2x10s and cut them in half.  Can extend the 1x4s 6 inches pass the out side rafters to get ten feet for no waste.

I would add a vertical to bolster the horizontals at the back if there is no other support. I would also more by the horizontals on the inside so that the firewood does not  push the horizontals out.

Depending on relative material costs and why it's this exact size now as modeled, it may be more efficient to start by designing the roof to make efficient use of locally available materials at standard overlap, and size the shed under it to suit. This is easy at the "modeled, not yet built" stage.

At 8'x3' you don't need rafters or purlins
most profiled sheet steel product can span 3 feet unsupported, (so just have the top and bottom beams)
eg:
Lysaght Trimdek Sheets:      0.42mm BMT   0.48mm BMT

Roofs   Single span          1100mm       1600mm
        End span             1300mm       1850mm
        Internal span        1900mm       2600mm
        Unstiffened overhang 150mm        300mm

ok 0.42mm thick is not going to do 5 feet unsupported,
but the thicker 0.48mm stuff will, also you can have almost 1 foot end overhangs instead,
How many panels? well when they make this this stuff comes off a roll and goes through a set of rollers that crease it up. So you can order any length you want. So just order the sheets you need.  They say the sheets cover 762mm wide (which is 30 inches even so - I bet they did that on purpose). So you'd need 3.6 sheets, so buy 4 and trim off the excess, roll it over the ends of the roof, or loose it in overlaps.
At 5 feet long transporting that should not be a problem, unless you are going by bus.
I can go down to the hardware store an get pre cut 1.8m sheets, but these will be the 0.42mm thickness and so would need a purlin in the middle, or I can go to the trade desk and order the 0.48mm thick, in any length I want. and in doing so save money by deleting the middle purlin.
These numbers are for an Australian product.  You should investigate what sheet roofing products are available locally, and then read the literature from the maker which will tell you how far it can span and what sort of fasteners you need to use.

If you use the thicker product (or local equivalent), you can lose the whole roof frame in this minimal shed case, just attaching to the beams front and back (let those stick out to the sides to support that less-stiff overhang) as the product can manage enough unsupported overhang front & back to give the desired coverage.

might need someting structural horizontally between the front and back posts, but yeah that.


You're not clear on what metal roofing product you intend to use, but nearly all of it has a stiffness axis (vertical) due to the formed ribs. It is not designed to span horizontally. Read the literature for your product. You can probably increase rafter interval and add 2x4 "purlins" to meet that requirement (or use lighter 1x4 or 2x3 purlins on your current rafter layout).

Square footage is square footage. Either size your roof for the roofing or buy the roofing necessary for your roof size. There are no theoretical wormholes to spare you from these two options. You might do with three roofing panels if you started with a half-rip and finished with the cutoff, and added butt laps in the runs as needed to use all material.



I agree with the above answer, but wish to add that the purlins used when building a metal roof must NOT be pressure treated. The chemicals used in the pressure treating react badly with the galvanized metal.
